# Method not found: 'setState' even though I'm in a Stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Problem. For the Past Days I've been playing around with Flutter. But now I hit a wall. My Problem is, that I'm in a List (List) inside a Stateful Widget. When i compile the App it says "Method not found: 'setState'." That Would make sense if i was in a Stateless widget but I am in a Stateful one so it should work.

This is my full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  runApp(MyApp());
}

double _value = 25.0;
bool _switchValue = false;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  Slider createState() => Slider();
}

class Slider extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          //width: (double.infinity),

            child: CupertinoSlider(
              value: _value,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 100.0,
              onChanged: (value){
                setState((){
                  _value = value;

                });
              },
            )
        ),
        MergeSemantics(
            child: CupertinoSwitch(
                value: _switchValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _switchValue = value;
                  });
                }
            )
        )
      ],
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  IconData icon_calender_state = CupertinoIcons.calendar_badge_plus;

  void _onItemTapped() {
  setState(() {
  if (_selectedIndex == 0){
    _selectedIndex = 1;
    icon_calender_state = CupertinoIcons.calendar_badge_minus;
    return;
  }
  if (_selectedIndex == 1){
    _selectedIndex = 0;
    icon_calender_state = CupertinoIcons.calendar_badge_plus;
    return;
  }

  });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(

            body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
              child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red])),
                child: Center(
                  child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
              ))),
              Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(icon_calender_state), onPressed: () {
                    _onItemTapped();
                  },),
    ],)),

    ],
    )));}
}
```

And This is only the part the error lies is. Every call of setState inside of the following list returns the said error.

```
class Slider extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          //width: (double.infinity),

            child: CupertinoSlider(
              value: _value,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 100.0,
              onChanged: (value){
                setState((){
                  _value = value;

                });
              },
            )
        ),
        MergeSemantics(
            child: CupertinoSwitch(
                value: _switchValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _switchValue = value;
                  });
                }
            )
        )
      ],
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Any suggestion how I should change my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're following some poor practice for flutter and storing widgets inside a variable. This is usually a big no-no as widgets are immutable and will not update as you expect them to.

Either declare the `List` within `build` or change it to a function that returns a `List` instead that is called in `build`

```dart
List<Widget> _widgetOptions() {
  return <Widget>[
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          //width: (double.infinity),

            child: CupertinoSlider(
              value: _value,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 100.0,
              onChanged: (value){
                setState((){
                  _value = value;

                });
              },
            )
        ),
        MergeSemantics(
            child: CupertinoSwitch(
                value: _switchValue,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _switchValue = value;
                  });
                }
            )
        )
      ],
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion using the function but the problem was i couldn't access it using an index. But then I tried declaring it inside of build and it worked. Thanks :D

Comment: @JuliusWaldmann If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted. As for the issue with the function, you likely didn't *call* the function properly and were trying to access an index of a function reference instead of the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher's answer tells you how to fix the problem, but what the problem actually was is that you are calling `setState` within the initializer for the `_widgetOptions` class field. You cannot use any of the class's members within an initializer in that class that is not marked `static` or otherwise accessible from a static context (i.e. without calling `this` either explicitly or implicitly). Since `setState` is an instance method and must be accessed by (implicitly) calling `this`, it doesn't yet exist when `_widgetOptions` is getting initialized.

Take the following, for example:

```dart
class Foo {
  // An instance method that does not exist until the constructor is called
  // and all instance initializers have run
  int a() { return 2; }

  // A static method that is created at the same time as the class type itself 
  // and exists before any constructors and instance initializers have run
  static int b() { return 3; }
  
  // This is fine
 int x = b();

  // This is also fine
  int y;
  void doSomething() {
    y = a();
  }

  // This will throw an error because `this` does not yet exist when `z` 
  // gets initialized and calling `a()` implicitly becomes `this.a()`
  int z = a();
}
```

Moving the initializer to within the `build` method or converting it to a method itself as Christopher suggests will solve the issue.

Comment: You can use non-const or non-static values in an initializer. The issue here is that it requires access to `this`, which does not exist at the time of field initialization as they are done before the constructor and you alluded to, but saying one cannot use values that are not constant or static in an initializer is a bit misleading.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore What I meant (and perhaps explained poorly) is that whatever is used must be accessible from a static context (i.e. without referencing `this` either explicitly or implicitly), and what that means about using the members of a class in the initializer is that they must be marked as either `static` or `const` (which I guess is redundant since `const` class members must also be marked `static`).